# Is knox token is safe are not?

Tags: json, django, django-rest-framework, jwt, django-rest-knox

I'm using Drf(django rest framework) for my back end development. I tried to use Knox-token for authentication and token generation. I new to this knox-token. I need to know is Knox token is safe are not?.
I'm going to develop web based product. So the product must be safe with full secure. Can i use **knox-token** for my product?

Answer (score 0):

**Knox provides an encrypted form of tokens before storing them in the database.** This feature would not allow any hacker to have access even if the database is compromised.

[https://www.section.io/engineering-education/api-authentication-with-django-knox-and-postman-testing/#:~:text=Knox%20provides%20an%20encrypted%20form,if%20the%20database%20is%20compromised](https://www.section.io/engineering-education/api-authentication-with-django-knox-and-postman-testing/#:%7E:text=Knox%20provides%20an%20encrypted%20form,if%20the%20database%20is%20compromised).

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/32521964)